# How to return array of json object - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some some data that I need to send to frontend as array of json objects, it basicly should have same structure as this json:

```
[{"vin":"U5YFF24128L064909","0":"U5YFF24128L064909","case_id":"1462538","1":"1462538","claimnumber":"E140039698","2":"E140039698","platenumber":"5M47465","3":"5M47465","axrmrs_id":"2051707","4":"2051707","insurer_memberid":"MM-O-8AB24F6D-1","5":"MM-O-8AB24F6D-1","country":"CZ","6":"CZ","date_created":"2014-02-10 00:00:00","7":"2014-02-10 00:00:00","totalloss":"N","8":"N","lastcalc_manufacturer_code":"28","9":"28","lastcalc_model_code":"25","10":"25","lastcalc_submodel_code":"07","11":"07","audavin_triggered":"","12":"","accident_date":"2014-02-02 00:00:00","13":"2014-02-02 00:00:00","registration_date":"2008-04-28 00:00:00","14":"2008-04-28 00:00:00","manufacturing_year":"2008","15":"2008","spareparts":"26573.4","16":"26573.4","totalcosts":"42187.47","17":"42187.47","laborhours":"7.3","18":"7.3","laborcosts":"3577","19":"3577","calculationdate":"2014-02-22 23:02:00","20":"2014-02-22 23:02:00","paintlabor":"5995","21":"5995","paintmaterial":"6042.07","22":"6042.07","currency":"CZK","23":"CZK","manufacturer":"KIA","24":"KIA","model":"CEED (ED)","25":"CEED (ED)","submodel":"ACTIVE","26":"ACTIVE","orgName":"Global Expert","27":"Global Expert","textL":"BLATN\u00cdK P PLAKOV\u00c1N\u00cd NOV\u00ddCH D\u00cdL\u016e,DVE\u0158E P PLAK POVRCHU,P\u0158-N\u00c1RAZN\u00cdKLAKOV\u00c1N\u00cd NOV\u00ddCH D\u00cdL\u016e","28":"BLATN\u00cdK P PLAKOV\u00c1N\u00cd NOV\u00ddCH D\u00cdL\u016e,DVE\u0158E P PLAK POVRCHU,P\u0158-N\u00c1RAZN\u00cdKLAKOV\u00c1N\u00cd NOV\u00ddCH D\u00cdL\u016e","textE":null,"29":null},{"vin":"U5YFF24128L064909","0":"U5YFF24128L064909","case_id":"1468328","1":"1468328","claimnumber":"5M47465","2":"5M47465","platenumber":"5M47465","3":"5M47465","axrmrs_id":"2037572","4":"2037572","insurer_memberid":"","5":"","country":"CZ","6":"CZ","date_created":"2014-02-13 00:00:00","7":"2014-02-13 00:00:00","totalloss":"","8":"","lastcalc_manufacturer_code":"28","9":"28","lastcalc_model_code":"25","10":"25","lastcalc_submodel_code":"07","11":"07","audavin_triggered":"","12":"","accident_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","13":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","registration_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","14":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","manufacturing_year":"2008","15":"2008","spareparts":"25319.55","16":"25319.55","totalcosts":"41529.62","17":"41529.62","laborhours":"7.7","18":"7.7","laborcosts":"3850","19":"3850","calculationdate":"2014-02-23 23:02:00","20":"2014-02-23 23:02:00","paintlabor":"5995","21":"5995","paintmaterial":"6042.07","22":"6042.07","currency":"CZK","23":"CZK","manufacturer":"KIA","24":"KIA","model":"CEED (ED)","25":"CEED (ED)","submodel":"ACTIVE","26":"ACTIVE","orgName":"0","27":"0","textL":"BLAT","textE":null,"29":null}]
```

How I try it:

```
foreach ( $array ['result'] ['claim'] as $claim )
    {

        $data = array (
            "claimnumber" =>$claim['@attributes']['id'],
            "date_created" =>$claim['country'],
            "country" =>$claim['creation'],
            "currency" =>$claim ['specific']['currency'],
            "insurer_memberid" =>$claim['insurance']['id'],
            "laborcosts" =>$claim ['specific']['partsCost'],
            "model" =>$claim ['specific']['model_name'],
            "orgName" =>$claim['insurance']['name'],
            "paintLabor" =>$claim['specific']['paintmaterial'],
            "totalcosts" =>$claim ['assessment']['damage-value']
        );
        $result = array();
        $result[] = $data;
        $result[] = array_push($result, $this->convertToJson($result));
    }
    echo $result;
```

But this return just string "Array", is there some nice way how to create API which display array of objects?

Thanks for any advise :)

Comment: Echo is for strings. I'm a fan of: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, 1) . '</pre>';` for arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the array before the loop, add the data within the loop, then json_encode and echo after the loop:

```
$result = array();
foreach ( $array ['result'] ['claim'] as $claim )
{

    $data = array (
        "claimnumber" =>$claim['@attributes']['id'],
        "date_created" =>$claim['country'],
        "country" =>$claim['creation'],
        "currency" =>$claim ['specific']['currency'],
        "insurer_memberid" =>$claim['insurance']['id'],
        "laborcosts" =>$claim ['specific']['partsCost'],
        "model" =>$claim ['specific']['model_name'],
        "orgName" =>$claim['insurance']['name'],
        "paintLabor" =>$claim['specific']['paintmaterial'],
        "totalcosts" =>$claim ['assessment']['damage-value']
    );
    $result[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you reset the `$result` variable in each loop. Change the code to:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array['result']['claim'] as $claim) {
    $result[] = array (
        "claimnumber"      => $claim['@attributes']['id'],
        "date_created"     => $claim['country'],
        "country"          => $claim['creation'],
        "currency"         => $claim['specific']['currency'],
        "insurer_memberid" => $claim['insurance']['id'],
        "laborcosts"       => $claim['specific']['partsCost'],
        "model"            => $claim['specific']['model_name'],
        "orgName"          => $claim['insurance']['name'],
        "paintLabor"       => $claim['specific']['paintmaterial'],
        "totalcosts"       => $claim['assessment']['damage-value']
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. array_push() takes first argument (the array) by reference, you don't need to assign it to $result.
   So it should be just `array_push($result, $this->convertToJson($result));`
2. To return json you can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function

   echo json_encode($result);

Answer (score 0):

Use print_r() method to print $result because $result is a array variable.

```
    $result = array();
    foreach ( $array ['result'] ['claim'] as $claim )
        {

            $data = array (
                "claimnumber" =>$claim['@attributes']['id'],
                "date_created" =>$claim['country'],
                "country" =>$claim['creation'],
                "currency" =>$claim ['specific']['currency'],
                "insurer_memberid" =>$claim['insurance']['id'],
                "laborcosts" =>$claim ['specific']['partsCost'],
                "model" =>$claim ['specific']['model_name'],
                "orgName" =>$claim['insurance']['name'],
                "paintLabor" =>$claim['specific']['paintmaterial'],
                "totalcosts" =>$claim ['assessment']['damage-value']
            );
            $result[] = $data;
            $result[] = array_push($result, $this->convertToJson($result));
        }
        print_r($result) ;
```